# Why is the chapter missing when importing with the \import command?

Tags: chapters, books, import

I am writing a report that contains a total of 6 chapters. I use the \import command to import them, but I have the following problem: if I try to import all the chapters, they appear up to the fourth one ("aircraft_aerosurfaces_dynamics"), otherwise, if I use the [draft] option on the fourth one, they all appear except the fourth one.
What could be the problem?

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
%
}
\opt{final}{% <===
   \import{aircraft_attitude/}{aircraft_attitude}
}

\opt{final}{% <===
   \import{aircraft_automated_navigation/}{aircraft_automated_navigation}
}

\opt{final}{% <===
   \import{aircraft_equations_of_motion/}{aircraft_equations_of_motion}
}
\opt{draft}{% <===
   \import{aircraft_aerosurfaces_dynamics/}{aircraft_aerosurfaces_dynamics}
}
\opt{final}{% <===
   \import{aircraft_dynamic_stability/}{aircraft_dynamic_stability}
}
\opt{final}{% <===
   \import{aircraft_turn_dynamics/}{aircraft_turn_dynamics}
}
```

I have noticed that if I import all the chapters, everything after the fourth chapter is not imported (i.e. appendix, glossary, bibliography, etc.).

Comment: you need to show an example presumably the `\import` command comes from the `import` package,  but what is the definition of `\opt` ? it isn't a standard command. If the run ends after the fourth chapter it presumably contains something that stops latex eg `\stop` or `\end{document}` take a copy of your document and delete everything that you can delete while still showing the problem, and post the example so people can debug it

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for your reply. The structure of my overleaf project was passed on to me by my professor. This structure is modular and each .tex file in it can be compiled separately.
Anyway I will follow your suggestion and let you know.